# php > array processing : good object-oriented library?

Tags: php, arrays

In my daily work as a php developer, I find myself here & again processing arrays.

Given :

```
$array1; // array to process
$keysToKeep         = ['k1', 'k2', 'k3'];
$keysToTranslate    = ['k1' => 'hello1'];
$keysToLower        = ['k2', 'k3'];
```

Typical example of process is :

```
$arrayProcessed = [];
foreach ($array1 as $k => $v) {
    if (array_key_exists($k, $keysToKeep) {
        $arrayProcessed[$k] = $v;
    }
    if (isset($keysToTranslate[$k]) ) {
        $arrayProcessed[$keysToTranslate[$k]] = $v;
        unset($arrayProcessed[$k]);
    }
}
foreach ($keysToLower AS $k) {
    if ($array_key_exists($k, $arrayProcessed) ) {
        $arrayProcessed[$k] = strtolower($array1[$k]);
    }
}
```

I dream of an api that would allow me to write this instead :

```
$arrayProcessed = owArray::getInstance($array1)
->keepKeys($keysToKeep)
->renameKeys($keysToTranslate)
->map($keysToLower, 'strtolower')
;
```

Can anyone point me to a library that goes in that direction ?

Thx in advance for any tips ;-)

Comment: I can't imagine it would be too hard to just make a function or a class that does this for you

Answer (score 0):

[Laravel](https://laravel.com/) has great [Collections](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/collections). Using them what you are trying to do can be written like this:

```
$array = [
    'k1' => 'Foo',
    'k2' => 'Bar',
    'k3' => 'Baz',
    'k4' => 'quux',
    'k5' => 'quuuux'
];

$keysToKeep         = ['k1', 'k2', 'k3'];
$keysToTranslate    = ['k1' => 'Hello1'];
$keysToLower        = ['k2', 'k3'];

$result = collect($array)
    ->only($keysToKeep)
    ->merge($keysToTranslate)
    ->pipe(function ($array) use ($keysToLower) {
        return $array->merge(
            $array->only($keysToLower)->map(function ($value) {
                return strtolower($value);
            })
        );
    })
    ->toArray();
```

The result will be:

```
array(3) {
  ["k1"]=>
  string(6) "Hello1"
  ["k2"]=>
  string(3) "bar"
  ["k3"]=>
  string(3) "baz"
}
```

And I am almost sure the last part (concerning `$keysToLower`) can be written even shorter.

There are a book and a course ["Refactoring to Collections"](https://adamwathan.me/refactoring-to-collections/) by [Adam Wathan](https://adamwathan.me/). Although they are not free, might be worth to check out.

Comment: Thx Sevavietl. Interesting api. Surprising instanciation : neither "new", nor static call. I guess the function returns an object...

Comment: @ffrey, yes, it is just a wrapper, that returns an instance of  `Illuminate\Support\Collection`.